# ## Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...): character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Tags: r, markdown

I have a weird error message popping up in a markdown in R. I am running this line of code
`heartrate_data[heartrate_data == "2022484408"] <- "user_6"`

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...): character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

I do not understand as I am not working with dates or attempting to use posix.. I am wondering if R is trying to pick up the numbers as a date in posixlt? How do I get rid of this error.

```
structure(list(Id = c(2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408, 
2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408
), Time = c("4/12/2016 7:21:00 AM", "4/12/2016 7:21:05 AM", "4/12/2016 
7:21:10 AM", 
"4/12/2016 7:21:20 AM", "4/12/2016 7:21:25 AM", "4/12/2016 7:22:05 AM", 
"4/12/2016 7:22:10 AM", "4/12/2016 7:22:15 AM", "4/12/2016 7:22:20 AM", 
"4/12/2016 7:22:25 AM"), Value = c(97L, 102L, 105L, 103L, 101L, 
95L, 91L, 93L, 94L, 93L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you

Comment: What does `class(heartrate_data)` return? It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick numeric, I included dput of this code. Is there anything else that would be helpful in this situation in regards to reproducible example?

Comment: So you posted `dput(heartrate_data)`. That should Rajeev returned a class of data.frame, not numeric if that’s the case. What are you trying to do wjth `heartrate_data==“2022484408”`? Are you trying to match the ID column? Because your Time column is a posix date time value. You aren’t clearly indexing either column which is odd.

Comment: I am attempting to change all "2022484408" Id values in heartrate_data to be "user_6" instead of the string of numbers. I did class(heartrate_data$Id) and received numeric class(heartrate_data) is data frame. my bad.

Comment: tag name for above comment @MrFlick

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

First, you seem to want to reference the `Id` column, but your filter expression references the whole `data.frame`.

Second, your `Id` column, as defined, is integer, not character so the filter condition will not work.

Third, you index a `data.frame` using, e.g., `df[<rowfilter>, ]` (note the comma after the filter condition.

So try this:

```
heartrate_data[heartrate_data$Id==2022484408, ]$Id <- 'user_6'
```

or

```
heartrate_data$Id[heartrate_data$Id==2022484408] <- 'user_6'
```

The first expression extracts the rows of `heartrate_data` meeting the filter condition and sets the `$Id` column in that subset to `'user_6'`.

The second expression references the `Id` column explicitly as a vector and sets all elements of that vecotr meeting the filter condition to `'user_6'`. In this case they both give the same result.

In either case the class of the `Id` column will be changed from integer to character and this change will apply to all the rows (including those not selected by the filter condition).

Comment: Cool thank you, so when you say the Id column will be changed from integer to character does this happen automatically with the expression? @jlhoward

Comment: Yes. R does not have strong typing, so the class (data type) of a vector, or a matrix, or a column of a `data.frame` will be changed automatically. Try `x <- 1:10; class(x); x[2] <- 'a'; class(x)`.